# get elements of a label with version before LATEST

Tags: clearcase

This command gets elements of a label with latest version:

cleartool find . -element "{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && version(/main/LATEST)}" -print

how do I get elements of a label with version before LATEST?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, how to get any version with the right label, but which aren't LATEST, you could do it in two passes:

```
cleartool find . -version "{lbtype_sub(LABEL1)}" -print > labelled_versions.txt
```

That would find all versions with the right label.

Remember a label can be applied to only *one* version per element.

You can restrict it per branch if you want:

```
cleartool find . -version "{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(myBranch)}" -print > labelled_versions.txt

# for instance, for main:

cleartool find . -version "{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(main)}" -print > labelled_versions.txt
```

(That would exclude versions labelled, but part of a different branch than `main`)

Then you can use a dynamic view, and for each version found, check if that version is the same as the one selected in your dynamic view (using [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)):

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%n" M:\MyView\myVob\path\to\myFile
```